What is the purpose of empty try block in the try-finally construction?
In the source code of ConcurrentBag in the TryTake method I can observe such code:
try { }
finally
{
    lockTaken = false; // reset lockTaken to avoid calling Monitor.Exit again in the finally block
    Monitor.Exit(list);
}

I familiar with monitors and understand the code like this, when the is some code inside try block:
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(obj, ref lockTaken);
    // some code here
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}

But this case with empty try block confuses me. Wouldn't it be the same if it will be just code from finally block without try-finally?

Don't be confused by code which does nothing. Why this construct is still in code? Probabaly it had some code in try-block, code was removed, try/finally wasn't.

I just followed the link. Could it be that it is in a finally block, because it needs to make sure it affects other code that is in a (different) finally block?

^^ --> tl;dr "This methodology guards against a Thread.Abort call interrupting the processing." which -if true- should have been documented there. That would really not be obvious, imho.

So by putting my entire app-code into the finally-block I ensure it won't be interupted by a Thread.Abort? Really not obvious and pretty strange.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain the Thread.Abort is not supported in .NET Core and .NET 5+, so all this has mostly historical value.
